# What is the meaning of this scope icon in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, icons, simulink

In [this MATLAB tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/examples/sl-design-optimization/906-design-optimization-to-meet-time-and-frequency-domain-requirements-gui), I encountered following icon. When you click on it, a scope opens. What is the scope's meaning and how can you insert it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subsystem "Pilot G-force calculation" has it's own simulink model inside it if you double click on it. 
This subsystem, in addition to the output (Nz Pilot, g) also has a scope on a signal.

When you run the model, you can just click on that scope icon instead of going inside the subsystem and then clicking on the scope to read the signal output as a variation of time.

**EDIT:**

The scope icon is a property of a signal called a **Viewer**. You can create different types of viewers for a signal connection (like scope, XY graphs, Eye diagrams, spectrum analysers etc), provided that signal is compatible with the viewer.

To test it, right click on a signal (any point on the line) and select suboption **Create & Connect Viewers**.

Best part above these viewers is that you can use it to compare the signal with any other signal in the model by a `2 x 1` axis Scope like in this example.

Comment: There are no scopes inside the subsystem, the scope icons plot the signals on which they are located.

Comment: My bad. Check the EDIT.

Answer (score 2):

It is a **signal viewer** . This can be used when you have many signal from different ports. Instead of using different scope block for different port signal you can use the signal viewer . You can configure signal viewer by using **Signal and scope Manager**.

Refer the Documentation

http://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/signal-and-scope-manager.html
http://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/signal-viewer-tasks.html